# Strange behavior: Cannot import data as MP3 format anymore

Tags: import, sound

I am having the strangest problem since a day: Mathematica is no longer (after a reinstall) able to import MP3 files.

I think these details should not be relevant, but they are all there are:

- It was doing this perfectly yesterday when I was running it from a different hard disk partition.
- I wanted to remove/replace the partition, so I reinstalled 
  (the same) Mathematica on the C:\ drive.
- The new installation no longer is able to import MP3 files.
- It is able to import image files, like jpeg but not audio mp3 files.

I found nothing on this on the web, and in case you don't believe me (I too found it incredulous at first), please see the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide an example file that will not import ?

Comment: If you really are certain you were doing the same thing yesterday, with the same files, same code etc. you might take a look at this support.wolfram.com/kb/12464 , it's an easy fix that sometimes helps with inexplicable behavior.

Comment: @image-doctor I could, but it might be pointless since it was the same as yesterday.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Thank you! clean start was a great idea, blanket solution for strange behavior.. I am editing the question with a _strange behavior_ prefix, so this could be a possible answer for someone in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to get an answer on this one, since it finally fixed someone's problem. Sometimes things get corrupted in MMA's initialization files which leads to strange, usually low-level complaints, e.g. can't import MP3. The fix is easy, so it's always a good first step when you see that red pop-up. (And confirmed that the user isn't to blame...)

To keep this answer self-contained, I've copied exactly the contents of [this page](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464) from Wolfram Support.

> How do I fix common problems by resetting Mathematica to its default
>   configuration?  Email  Print Many issues with system installation can
>   be fixed by resetting Mathematica‘s preferences. Starting the product
>   with cleared preferences returns it to its default configuration by
>   deleting and recreating internal files located in the Base Directory
>   and the User Base Directory. You can find their locations on your
>   computer by evaluating $BaseDirectory and $UserBaseDirectory in a
>   Wolfram notebook. If you have saved anything to these directories,
>   please back them up before performing a clean start. If you have
>   edited any init.m files, they would be located in these directories.
>   After performing the clean start, Mathematica may need to be activated
>   again. You can access your activation information through the Wolfram
>   User Portal.
>
> Windows To perform a clean start on Windows, start Mathematica while
>   holding down the Ctrl and Shift keys. Keep the keys held down until
>   the Mathematica screen appears. If this does not address the issue,
>   you can perform a clean start manually by deleting the Base Directory
>   and User Base Directory on the computer.
>
> On Windows Vista, 7, 8, and 8.1, by default these directories are
>   located at:
>
> C:\ProgramData\Mathematica C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica
>   where  is your username on the computer.
>
> These files may be hidden on your computer. You may need to enable
>   your account to see hidden files.
>
> Mac To perform a clean start on a Mac, start Mathematica while holding
>   down the Option and Shift keys. Keep the keys held down until one the
>   Mathematica screen appears. If this does not address the issue, you
>   can perform a clean start manually by deleting the Base Directory and
>   User Base Directory on the computer. By default these are located at:
>
> /Library/Mathematica ~/Library/Mathematica These files may be hidden
>   on your computer. To navigate to a hidden folder, open the Finder
>   application. Press Command + Shift + G to open a file search dialog
>   and enter “~/Library/Mathematica/”. Finder opens the hidden folder.
>
> Linux To perform a clean start on Linux, start Mathematica by running
>   the following in your terminal:
>
> mathematica -cleanstart If this does not address the issue, you can
>   perform a clean start manually by deleting the Base Directory and User
>   Base Directory on the computer. By default these are located at:
>
> /usr/share/Mathematica ~/.Mathematica