# Slow front end Mathematica 11.0.1 on linux

Tags: front-end, linux, system-performance

Is anyone also experiencing rather slow front end behaviour in Mathematica 11.0.1 on Linux (Deb 8.7 + kde)? I am experiencing quite slower saving times of notebooks themselves and slower response times of GUI (compared to the same version on the same machine under windows 7). Sometimes after having Mathematica open for longer time (~hrs), the gui freezes completely.

The resolution is to periodically completely close mathematica and start again as soon as the gui responsivness becomes slower.

Comment: I have *not* noticed this on MMA 11.0.1, Ubuntu 15.10 or Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Me neither, on Gentoo Linux. The only times when things become really slow is when I have a lot of complicated graphics printed to the notebook frontend.

Answer (score 7):

I have experienced this (with M11 on a KDE-based Linux). This will sound ridiculous, but try copying any piece of text (need not be from within Mathematica) to the clipboard. Mathematica immediately stopped being sluggish. More extensive description here: [Mathematica 10 on Ubuntu: Extremely slow input and random key inputs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92713/mathematica-10-on-ubuntu-extremely-slow-input-and-random-key-inputs/181305#181305)

Comment: Interestingly I sometimes have a problem in a similar area - when there's a lot of stuff on my clipboard, MMA windows take a long time to activate in the window manager in OSX.